# Does a child div inherit parent's height?

Tags: css, inheritance

As far as I know, child divs normally inherit parent's style. However this isn't the case when I am trying to copy the parent's height. Any clarification on how this works would be very appreciated

#### Parent Div

[image]

#### Child Div

[image]

I've tried switching to `position:relative` and `display:inline` but am yet to find anything that modifies the child div's height relative to the parent.

```js
// Plot our graphs
var data = [
  {
    z: [[1, 20, 30], [20, 1, 60], [30, 60, 1]],
    type: 'heatmap'
  }
];

Plotly.newPlot('chart_div', data);
```

```css
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ FONT ]*/
@font-face {
  font-family: Ubuntu-Regular;
  src: url('../fonts/ubuntu_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'); 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Ubuntu-Bold;
  src: url('../fonts/ubuntu-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'); 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
  src: url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'); 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'); 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Material-Design-Iconic-Font;
  src: url('../fonts/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.woff') format('woff'); 
}


fontawesome-webfont.woff

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ RESTYLE TAG ]*/

* {
 margin: 0px; 
 padding: 0px; 
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
 height: 100%;
 font-family: Ubuntu-Regular, sans-serif;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
a {
 font-family: Ubuntu-Regular;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.7;
 color: #666666;
 margin: 0px;
 transition: all 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
}

a:focus {
 outline: none !important;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
  color: #403866;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
 margin: 0px;
}

p {
 font-family: Ubuntu-Regular;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.7;
 color: #666666;
 margin: 0px;
}

ul, li {
 margin: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
}


/*---------------------------------------------*/
input {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
}

textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
  border-color: transparent !important;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
input:-moz-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
input::-moz-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
textarea:-moz-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
textarea::-moz-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
button {
 outline: none !important;
 border: none;
 background: transparent;
}

button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

iframe {
 border: none !important;
}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Utility ]*/
.txt1 {
  font-family: Ubuntu-Regular;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #827ffe;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.app-explanation {
  font-family: Ubuntu-Regular;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #403866;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  width: 100%;
}



/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ login ]*/

.limiter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-login100 {
  width: 100%;  
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;;
}


.wrap-login100 {
  width: 390px;;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap-data100 {
  width: 90%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}


/*==================================================================
[ Form ]*/

.login100-form {
  width: 100%;
}

.login100-form-title {
  font-family: Ubuntu-Bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #403866;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;

  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}



/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Input ]*/

.wrap-input100 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/*---------------------------------------------*/
.input100 {
  font-family: Ubuntu-Bold;
  color: #403866;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 18px;

  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  height: 62px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 38px;
}
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Focus Input ]*/

.focus-input100 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid #827ffe;
  border-radius: 3px;

  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;

  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.3);
  -o-transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.3);
  transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.3);
}

.input100:focus + .focus-input100 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.eff-focus-selection {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}


/*==================================================================
[ Restyle Checkbox ]*/

.input-checkbox100 {
  display: none;
}

.label-checkbox100 {
  font-family: Ubuntu-Regular;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #999999;
  line-height: 1.2;

  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label-checkbox100::before {
  content: "\f00c";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: transparent;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #827ffe;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.input-checkbox100:checked + .label-checkbox100::before {
  color: #827ffe;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Button ]*/
.container-login100-form-btn {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.login100-form-btn {
  font-family: Ubuntu-Bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 62px;
  background-color: #827ffe;
  border-radius: 3px;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.login100-form-btn:hover {
  background-color: #403866;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Alert validate ]*/

.validate-input {
  position: relative;
}

.alert-validate::before {
  content: attr(data-validate);
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 70%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c80000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 4px 25px 5px 10px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 12px;
  pointer-events: none;

  font-family: Ubuntu-Regular;
  color: #c80000;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: left;

  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

.alert-validate::after {
  content: "\f12a";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  color: #c80000;
  font-size: 18px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 18px;
}

.alert-validate:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .alert-validate::before {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/*==================================================================
[ Restyle Select2 ]*/

.select2-container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  width: auto !important;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(171, 171, 189, 0.233);
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ in select ]*/
.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  font-family: Ubuntu-Bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555555;
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding-left: 0px ;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.select2-selection__arrow b {
  display: none;
  font-family: Material-Design-Iconic-Font !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555555;
}

.select2-selection__arrow {
  content: '\f312';
  font-family: Material-Design-Iconic-Font !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555555;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Dropdown option ]*/
.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown {
  z-index: 1251;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:  rgba(171, 171, 189, 0.233);
  left: -40px;

  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .select2-container--open .select2-dropdown {
    left: -12px;
  }
}

.select2-dropdown--above {top: -38px;}
.select2-dropdown--below {top: 10px;}

.select2-container .select2-results__option[aria-selected] {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 24px;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .select2-container .select2-results__option[aria-selected] {
    padding-left: 12px;
  }
}

.select2-container .select2-results__option[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: #403866;
  color: white;
}

.select2-container .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
  background: #827ffe;
  color: white;
}

.select2-results__options {
  font-family: Ubuntu-Bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555555;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Ubuntu-Bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.wrap-input100 .dropDownSelect2 .select2-container--open {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.wrap-input100 .dropDownSelect2 .select2-dropdown {
  width: calc(100% + 2px) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Blackfynn Exporter</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico" />
 <!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="build/build.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 

 <div id='half-height' style="height: 40% !important">
  <div id='blackfynn-panel' style="position: relative">

   <div class="container-login100 datasetUI" id="dataset_div">
    <div class="wrap-data100 p-t-50 p-b-90 datasetUI">
     <form class="contact100-form validate-form">
      <span class="login100-form-title p-b-51">
       Data Viewer
      </span>
      <div class=" input100 wrap-input100 input100-select bg1 datasetUI">
       <span class="label-input100"></span>
       <div id="channel_div">
        <select class="js-select2" name="service" id="select_channel">
         <option>Channel Selection</option>
        </select>
        <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
       </div>
      </div>


     </form>

     <div class="datasetUI" id="chart_div"></div>
     <br>
     <div id="exportURL">
     </div>

    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--===============================================================================================-->
 <!--===============================================================================================-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: height is not inherited. Here you are restriciting the height of the parent so the child is overflowinh

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif How can I restrict child height so it is inherited?

Comment: add the height restriction for the needed element, so you should do height:100% for the child for example so it's take 100% of the parent height that is 40% of it's parent (body) that is 100% of its parent (html) and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child element does not inherit the height of its parent.

[image: MDN]

[Reference: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)

You can however set its value to `height:inherit;` [CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/LouBagel/pen/wbQqOV)

You could also use `height: 100%` or `max-height: 100%`

In any situation you have to think what you want to do with the content if it is too much to fit in that set height: `overflow: hidden`; `overflow-y:hidden`; `overflow-y: scroll`.